# Filter and group the values in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a file with below content:

```
a.ganesh : sp-tns-ops-dashboard
a.ganesh : tns-extern
a.shahnawaz : pricing-dm-rest
a.shubhamkumar : apl
aadhar.sachdeva : athena
aakash.j : cms-cs-gateway
aakash.j : cms-enrichment-console
aakash.j : sp-slm-sps-external
aakash.j : preprod-cms-localisation-gateway
```

I am trying to filter and get the output in below format:

```
[[a.ganesh: ["sp-tns-ops-dashboard", "tns-extern"]], [a.shahnawaz: ["pricing-dm-rest"]], [aakash.j: ["cms-cs-gateway", "cms-enrichment-console", "sp-slm-sps-external", "preprod-cms-localisation-gateway"]]]
```

Tried something like:

```
def test():
    lst1 = []
    for i in open("sorted_list.txt").readlines():
        strip = i.strip()
        parts = lst1.append(strip.split(":"))
    lst2 = []
    for j in lst1:
        if j[0] not in lst2:
            lst2.append(f"{j[0]} : {j[1]}")
            print(lst2)
```

I understand there's a logic mistake, but can I get a help here

Comment: Did you mean the list of directories? The output you show us is not compatible with any direct Python type. I mean it should be like that: `[{a.ganesh: ["sp-tns-ops-dashboard", "tns-extern"]}]` ...

Comment: @gorzk my bad, it should be list of directories

Answer (score 1):

Try to *play* with this:

```py
keys = set()
dictList = dict()

for l in lst1:
    keys.add(l[0])
    dictList.setdefault(l[0],[]).append(l[1])

lst2 = dictList.items()
```